# What configurations can be adjusted to improve the query performance of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to know what parameter configurations can be adjusted to optimize the performance of Apache IoTDB? Currently I only adjust the memory size distributed to IoTDB, but now the speed of query results returned is very slow, sometimes it takes tens of seconds to see the results. Therefore, I want to know what settings can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

The `Query Configurations` in `iot-common.properties` directory of Apache IoTDB can be changed, you can study the parameters to adjust.